# How to solve this geometric problem with Mathematica?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry, logic, synthetic-geometry

I try to  solve  the following problem, making use of 14.0 on Windows 10

> Let a triangle $\Delta$ (a contour with its interior) be chosen in the unit square $S$.
> To prove that the closure of the difference of the sets  $\overline{S\setminus \Delta}$ includes a triangle of the area
> at least $1/6$

Here are my unsuccessful attempts. First, I try to apply quantifiers  to this
end.
Let us denote the coordinates of the vertices of the chosen triangle by `{x1,x2}, {y1,y2}, {z1,z2}`
and the coordinates of the vertices of the the desired triangle by `{a1,a2}, {b1,b2}, {c1,c2}`.
The quantifiers do not directly work with`Region`s, so `RegionMember`is needed to be used to rewrite  regions as systems of algebraic equations and inequalities.

The command

```
ForAll[{x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2},  x1 >= 0 && x1 <= 1 && y1 >= 0 && y1 <= 1 && y2 >= 0 && 
y2 <= 1 &&  z1 >= 0 && z2 <= 1,  Exists[{a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2}, 
RegionMember[RegionDifference[Rectangle[],
Triangle[{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2}}]], {a1, a2}] && 
RegionMember[RegionDifference[Rectangle[], 
Triangle[{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2}}]], {b1, b2}] && 
 RegionMember[RegionDifference[Rectangle[], 
 Triangle[{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2}}]], {c1, c2}], 
 Area[Triangle[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}]] >= 1/6 && 
 ForAll[{x, y},Implies[RegionMember[Triangle[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}], {x, y}], 
 RegionMember[RegionConvert[RegionDifference[Rectangle[], 
 Triangle[{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2}}]], "Implicit"], {x,y}]]]]]
```

seems  syntactically correct. Unfortunately,

```
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

> The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation

on my comp (which is not powerful) in several hours.

Second, I try to apply `NMaximize` to find a desired triangle by

```
f[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ, y1_?NumericQ, y2_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ] := 
 NMaximize[{Area[ Triangle[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}]], 
(RegionConvert[ RegionDifference[Rectangle[], 
     Triangle[{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2}}]], 
    "Implicit"] /. {\[FormalX] -> a1, \[FormalY] -> a2})[[1]]
&& (RegionConvert[ RegionDifference[Rectangle[], 
     Triangle[{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2}}]], 
    "Implicit"] /. {\[FormalX] -> b1, \[FormalY] -> b2})[[
 1]] && (RegionConvert[RegionDifference[Rectangle[], 
     Triangle[{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2}}]], 
    "Implicit"] /. {\[FormalX] -> c1, \[FormalY] -> c2})[[1]] && 
RegionIntersection[RegionDifference[Rectangle[], 
   Triangle[{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2}}]], 
  Triangle[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}]] == 
 Triangle[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}]}, {a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2}]
```

and then to `NMinimize` the function `f`, but

```
f[1/4, 0.3, 1/4, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8]
```

> NMaximize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: {Triangle[{{a1,a2},{b1,b2},{c1,c2}}]
> ==BooleanRegion[{#1,#2}&,{Polygon[{{<<2>>},{<<2>>},{<<2>>},{<<2>>}}->{{<<3>>}}],
> Triangle[{{a1,a2},{b1,b2},{c1,c2}}]}],0. +1. a1<=1.,<<6>>,-0.8 c1-0.2 c2<=-0.8,-0.2 c1+0.2 c2<=0.}.
> Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables.

I don't think `GeometricTest` is able to solve it at the present and, as far as my knowledge goes,
[AlphaGeometry](https://deepmind.google/discover/blog/alphageometry-an-olympiad-level-ai-system-for-geometry/?fbclid=IwAR2N9TCsStdz4aEHBs86dOkuo04VEw0N83f-EvqsYBYPGH9r6WmbHgekrF0)
is not implemented in Mathematica yet.

Edit. In order to make the formulation more accurate, the difference of the sets $S\setminus \Delta$ is replaced by the closure of the difference of the sets  $\overline{S\setminus \Delta}$.

Comment: Please, don't edit the question, you may suggest changes in your comments to the question.

Comment: It is not fair to down vote without explanation.

Comment: (+1) I think we can assume that the three points of the first triangle are all on the edges of such unit square,right?

Comment: @cvgmt: Thank you for your interest to the question. No, there is not such a condition in the formulation of the problem. The proof of the possibility of that restriction is not clear to me.

Comment: A picture could help to clarify the question

Answer (score 2):

Based on the interesting answer of @three777 we can define quite general triangle depending on three paramters `0<\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma] <1` as shown in the picture

```
Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, {\[Alpha], 0}}], 
   Arrow[{{1, 0}, { 1, \[Beta]}}], Arrow[{{1, 1}, {1 - \[Gamma], 1}}],
    Text["\[Alpha]", {\[Alpha], 0}/2, {0, -1}], 
   Text["\[Beta]", { 1, \[Beta]/2}, { 1, 0}], 
   Text["\[Gamma]", {1 - \[Gamma]/2, 1}, {0, 1}], FaceForm[None], 
   EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[], FaceForm[Red], 
   Triangle[{{\[Alpha], 0}, { 1, \[Beta]}, {1 - \[Gamma], 1}}]
   } /. {\[Alpha] -> .2, \[Beta] -> .3, \[Gamma] -> .9}]
```

[image]

Minimization of the four neighboring triangles gives

```
sol = Minimize[{
Max[{ Cross[{\[Alpha], 0}] . {1 - \[Gamma], 1}/2,Cross[{1 - \[Gamma], 1}] . {0, 1}/2 , (1 - \[Alpha]) \[Beta]/2, (1 - \[Beta]) \[Gamma]/2}] }
, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}]

(*{1/6, {\[Alpha] -> 1/3, \[Beta] -> 1/2, \[Gamma] -> 2/3}}*)

Graphics[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, {\[Alpha], 0}}], 
   Arrow[{{1, 0}, { 1, \[Beta]}}], Arrow[{{1, 1}, {1 - \[Gamma], 1}}],
    FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[], FaceForm[Red], 
   Triangle[{{\[Alpha], 0}, { 1, \[Beta]}, {1 - \[Gamma], 1}}]
   } /. sol[[2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is not it, The vertices of the triangle $\Delta$ from the question are not assumed to belong to the sides of the square $S$ and this is noticed in the comments to the question. I will be waiting for serious and rich-in-content answers.

Comment: It is quite obvious that scenario with triangle vertices laying on the boundary of the square is equivalent to the general problem. Similarly, a problem of finding a prime that divides a large number does not mean that you have to divide it by all prime numbers starting from `2` until you find a divisor. There are much clever methods.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Thanks for your competent comment. It is quite obvious that we only need to consider the three boundary regions which follow from the extended triangular sides. user64494's  rating " waiting for serious and rich-in-content answers" is simply out of place and unnecessary , I think

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{Transparent, EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, 
   Black, Triangle[{{0, a}, {1/2, 1}, {1, a}}], 
   Arrow[{{1.05, 0}, {1.05, a}}], Arrow[{{1.05, a}, {1.05, 0}}], 
   Inset["a", {1.08, a/2}], Red, Triangle[{{1/2, 1}, {1, a}, {1, 1}}],
    Green, Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, a}}]}], {{a, 1/3}, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Minimizing max of red and green triangle areas.

```
Minimize[Max@{Area@Triangle[{{1/2, 1}, {1, a}, {1, 1}}], 
   Area@Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, a}}]}, a]
```

$$\left\{\frac{1}{6},\left\{a\to \frac{1}{3}\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: Thank you for your interest to the question and work. First, you consider a special case `Triangle[{{0, a}, {1/2, 1}, {1, a}}]`. Second, `Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, a}}]` and `Triangle[{{1/2, 1}, {1, a}, {1, 1}}]` are not logically derived. Corollary: this is not it.  I will be waiting for serious and rich-in-content answers.

Comment: This is a colored illustration of the question under consideration for special case. If I were you, I don't post it at all.

Comment: (+1) This answer is more "serious and rich-in-content" that the question.

Comment: @azerbajdzan: Unfortunately, your emotional  personal  opinion is not grounded. TNX anyway.